# How to find element, selector with dynamically added data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I am dynamically adding to some elements in my page data attribute, but after when I'm trying to find them on some click event the result is undefined, null. I've tried this ways but none of them work...

```
var selector = $(document).find('*').attr('[data-step]');

var selector = $(document).find('*').attr('data-step');

var selector = $(document).find('*').prop('data-step');

var selector = $(document).find('[data-step]');
```

Can any body help?

Comment: How do you add these data attributes? Provide more context regarding your question

Comment: simple `selector.data('step', '1');`

Comment: To what element do you add these attributes?

Comment: So you aren't adding data attribute but setting data object property. You should use `filter()` method instead. That's said, still missing some context regarding your question. If you add yourself these datas, you already know which elements has this data set

Comment: If you plan to select element later by data-attribute then set attribute `selector.attr('data-step', 1);`.

Comment: have you done inspect element to check whether the property added properly.